# php Redirect not working on new setup

Tags: php, apache

I have purchased a new machine and placed the current versions of Apache and php on the machine.  I have transferred my sites into the Apache htdoc dir.  Sites that I host my self and have a index.php work correctly.  Two sites that I have a index.php with a redirect in the file do not work.  When you go to the site www.mercedesauman.com nothing happens, it does not redirect.  This is what I have for the index.php file for the one of the sites that I want redirected.

```
    <?
    header('Location: http://aumanme93.wixsite.com/mercedes');
    die;
    ?>
```

Not understanding why it does not work?  Works on old machine, is there something in Apache httpd.conf file that needs to be added or changed?

Comment: may be short tags somehow not working on new machine, try to put `<?php` instead of `<?` and also try with removing `die`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php
    header('Location: http://aumanme93.wixsite.com/mercedes');
    ?>
```

Try this. `<??>` tag is used when short tag is enabled in php.ini.
And die function is not needed.

Comment: Thank you, that worked. why does it make a difference if the "php" is there?

Comment: At first, old php version supports <??> and <?php ?>, but nowadays, newer php version recommends only <?php ?> tag.